# Switch giving wrong values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, compare

Running the following code in Google Chrome I have the switch statement going to default when comparing minus.  Why am I encountering this issue? How can I solve it?
Thank you all in advance!

```
var code="F+F−F−F+F"
for(var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {      
    alert(code[i]);
    switch(code[i]) {
        case 'F':
            alert("F");
            break;

        case 'G':
            alert("G");
            break;
        case '+':
            alert("+");
            break;

        case '-':
            alert("-");
            break;

        default:
            alert("default");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: look carefully at the width of your "minuses" -- they aren't the same character...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `−` does not equals `-`

Comment: I had to wait a brief period of time before i could do it